# extjs tree component not being rendered correctly

Tags: extjs4, javascript-framework

im having a hard time learning ExtJS. inspite of the fact that almost everywhere it was mentioned that it was the easiest compared to others like DOJO.
what iam trying to create is a simple tree (NO MVC.. just a simple tree).
heres my javascript code..

```
 Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            title: 'Simple Tree',
            width: 150,
            height: 150,
            root: {
                text: 'Root',
                expanded: true,
                children: [
                    {
                        text: 'Child 1',
                        leaf: true
                    },
                    {
                        text: 'Child 2',
                        leaf: true
                    },
                    {
                        text: 'Child 3',
                        expanded: true,
                        children: [
                            {
                                text: 'Grandchild',
                                leaf: true
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        });
```

and only something like a panel is being rendered on the body.
html is this

```
<body>
    <div>

    </div>
</body>
```

what am i doing wrong?
**UPDATE:-** 
1.whole of the javascript here is placed in the page after the body tag.
2. im including bootstrap.js jsvascript file that is bundeled with ExtJS download.

Comment: There seems to be no problem with your code. Here is the code running: http://jsfiddle.net/FULtb/ Do you get any error on firebug or chrome console?

Comment: no--no errors in chrome or in ie.. what im getting is a panel on the web page and nothing else

Comment: oops what i was missing was Ext.onReady() but i dont understand why it was needed when i included the script at the end and panel was being rendered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Ext.create()` function should have been called inside `Ext.onReady()` otherwise some elemnts are rendered and others are not

Comment: The squared bracket after the 2.cildern is waste. To get 'Grandchild' == ...root.children[2]["children"]**[0]**["text"]. There is a use less array level with a length of 1. This could be the pitfall later.